# installing SSL on 2 exchange servers

Tags: ssl, exchange, ssl-certificate, email-server

I have 2 exchange servers run for one email service, and I need to renew the SSL certificate. Do I need to issue 2 SSL, or one is enough?
If one is enough how can I replicate it between them?

Comment: Is it the same certificate? If so, you only need one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A special Rpc error occurs on server EX2: Cannot import certificate. A certificate with the thumbprint ............... already exists.

Refer to the [blog](https://supertekboy.com/2015/10/23/a-certificate-with-the-thumbprint-already-exists/) to try to resolve this issue. If it cannot work for your issue, try running command in cmd, run: [certutil](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil#-repairstore) -repairstore My “paste the thumbprint in here” And check if this issue continues. Above solutions are provided in the similar thread for your reference: [Certificate renew error thumbprint already exist](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2158636-certificate-renew-error-thumbprint-already-exist)

If all above solution don't work for you, the easier way to resolve this issue is recreating new certificate request for the server 2. You also can refer to the similar thread: [A certificate with the thumbprint...already exists.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/e88dd7b8-4b46-4c9b-b993-c31305a3a049/a-certificate-with-the-thumbprintalready-exists?forum=exchange2010)

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to renew the cert for one and then copy the cert over to the other Exchange Server and Import it into the Cert store for the second Server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assist, In the first server, I have created the request, then I got "complete" button, then I press the "complete" and point to the .cer file, I think its done. now in the second server, when I press the 3 dots button and chose import, I got this error "A special Rpc error occurs on server EX2: Cannot import certificate. A certificate with the thumbprint ............... already exists."

Comment: Does the file have the same name as the old file?